# Gender neutral reflexive pronoun — equivalent to "himself" and "herself"

Tags: pronouns, reflexives, singular-they

How would you refer to a gender neutral subject with a [reflexive pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun)?

> It is unbelievable how a perpetrator will cast **oneself** in the role of victim.

That does not seem right.  Is there a better word other than "oneself"?  I thought "oneself" would refer to the narrator.  Here I try to refer to the subject.

**Themselves:** It is possible to use a ['singular they'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) for pronouns, but to say "themselves" surely can not be correct as a gender neutral reflexive pronoun?  According to [this article](http://www.justice.gc.ca/fra/min-dept/pub/legis/n39.html), it would only seem to make sense when qualified by a singular they.

**Themself:** "The form is not widely accepted in standard English" [according to the Oxford dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/themself).

> It is unbelievable how they, as a perpetrator, will cast **themselves** in the role of victim.

I'd like to avoid making the sentence this complex.

Comment: I, personally, would just use *themself*, wide acceptance in standard English be damned.

Comment: Maybe it's an age-related thing. I don't think I particularly interpret *himself* here as implying the perp is a male. The fact that I *do* think "he" is more likely to be male is mainly because in the real world more males than females are so classified. "*If person could die if he ate rat poison*" implies very little about gender to me.

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary may cast aspersions upon "themself", but the Oxford English Dictionary mentions the use of both "themself" and "themselves" with singular antecedents, with no suggestion that the use is problematic.  ("Themselves" is used in constructions where it is paired with things like "Every one", "themself" in constructions like yours.)

Comment: Everyone saying you can just substitute "him or herself" is missing the fact that some people use gender neutral pronouns. Ie.) trans* and genderqueer individuals. So...the correct pronoun to refer to someone who uses gender neutral pronouns would be neither "himself" nor "herself." And sorry...but working with "the queer community" doesn't entitle you to choose a pronoun for someone else. There are a whole lot of genders and pronouns out there. You can no more use "hir" to cover all your bases than you can use "him." It's not a cover-all-your-bases with a randomly selected pronoun kind of sit

Comment: I'm a native speaker of the UK and an English language teacher, and I have always used, and will continue to use 'themselves' and 'they' for the singular gender neutral reference: "The child can count themselves lucky they didn't cause a fire." It's fine by me, and widely used.

Comment: Closely related: [The hidden flaw in “singular they”—what to do about reflexive pronouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617)

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/themself) has this 2019 update: 'Themself: is it ever okay to say 'themself'? ... As singular they becomes more widely accepted—and increasingly adopted formally by even traditional news outlets—the reflexive pronoun that logically goes with it is gaining traction too.'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just another version of the he/she, him/her dilemma: English lacks singular pronouns that include both genders. I like @drm65's approach to avoiding the problem. The other likely option is to specify both:

*"himself or herself"*

> It is unbelievable how a perpetrator will cast himself or herself in the role of victim.

Or:

*"him or herself"*

> It is unbelievable how a perpetrator will cast him or herself in the role of victim.

**Update:**

Another approach is to just choose a verb that isn't reflexive:

*It is unbelievable how a perpetrator will play the role of victim.*

That's not always possible or best, e.g. when you're trying to emphasize exactly that reflexive aspect of the issue. But *play* is obviously shorter and simpler than *cast him or herself in the role of*, so it's worth considering unless there's a good reason to use the wordier version.

**Update 2:**

This question and my original answer are nearly 9 years old now, and there have been some significant changes with respect to personal pronouns in the interim. There's a greater awareness now of gender neutral and non-binary pronouns. In some contexts, a phrase like *him or herself* that's meant to be inclusive (compared to just *himself*) might be insensitive. [*Themself*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/themself) seems to be [gaining acceptance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=themself&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthemself%3B%2Cc0) even if it's not yet widely used. As the obvious singular form of the [commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=themselves&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthemselves%3B%2Cc0) *themselves*, *themself* seems like a good choice for being inclusive while still being fairly conventional.

There are a number of other gender neutral third person reflexive pronouns such as [*hirself*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hirself), [*zirself*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zirself), [*xyrself*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xyrself), and [*coself*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coself). If you're talking about a specific person and know which pronouns they favor, use them.

Perhaps by 2029 there will be a more clear-cut answer.

Comment: "Himself or herself" isn't such a great option if you're trying to be inclusive towards non-binary gender identities (those who identify as a "they," not a "he" or "she"). I wouldn't use it, personally.

Answer (score 23):

You could circumvent the problem *and* avoid overcomplexity by merely pluralizing the subject:

> It is unbelievable how perpetrators will cast themselves in the role of victim.

This is what I would do in this case, as neither *oneself*, *themselves*, or *themself* are widely endorsed here, and as there is no such thing in English as a singular gender neutral reflexive pronoun.

Comment: I disagree with the notion of there being such a thing as "strict" correctness-- it's just arbitrary opinion at the end of the day (practically no language has a 1-1 correspondence between its pronouns and the precise types/combinations of people they refer to-- you can probably invent spurious reasons for saying that any use of any pronoun is "incorrect" if you go down that road). But, I agree with your pragmatic solution to allay potential whingers.

Comment: +1 as the only logical alternative would be "itself" - and that probably won't fly in general usage :)

Comment: "[...]as there is no such thing in English as a singular gender neutral reflexive pronoun"... yet.

Comment: @Neil: I edited the strictness out of the answer.

Comment: @Neil: There is such a thing as strictness, though, and that was my point.

Comment: I have ticked the 'himself or herself' answer as this is a workaround.  You may want to be talking about somebody specific where the gender is unknown.  *"The perpetrator let himself or herself in via the backdoor."*  This answer does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 18):

The word *themself* has been used for centuries in conjunction with the singular gender-neutral "they". The singular "they" fell into disrepute among prescriptive grammarians, and brought the word *themself* with it.  Since we are now reviving the singular "they" (which was in disrepute with the prescriptive grammarians), there is no reason we shouldn't revive *themself* as well.

Comment: I agree with this very sensible answer, for reasons spelled out at somewhat greater length in my answer to the closely related question [The hidden flaw in "singular 'they"—what to do about reflexive pronouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617/the-hidden-flaw-in-singular-they-what-to-do-about-reflexive-pronouns)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stretch the boundaries of English:

Working with the Queer Community, I've found `hir` [hēr] (∴`hirself`) to be the most intuitive/easy to assimilate neologism.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_pronoun#cite_ref-25

Comment: How do you pronounce 'hir' and 'hirself'?  If it's pronounced the same as 'her' and 'herself' it would convey a feminine connotation.

Comment: @James it's pronounced with the e from `he`: ē. Very similar to `hear` or `here`, but with emphasis on the vowel.

Comment: @Shad: It's hard enough introducing a new pronoun; introducing a new sound with it that most Americans can't pronounce is clearly a bad idea. Please just tell people it's pronounced *here-self*.