# What is a proper gender-neutral form of himself or herself

Tags: singular-they, gender-neutral, generic-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) 
>   [Gender neutral reflexive pronoun — equivalent to “himself” and “herself”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35135/gender-neutral-reflexive-pronoun-equivalent-to-himself-and-herself)

I am thinking "themself" is a very old deprecated way of saying this.  What would be more proper?

An example would be:

One does not simply build Rome themself.

It just seems awkward with "themself."

Comment: How about *oneself*?

Comment: I'm not sure [deprecated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deprecate) means what you think it does.

Comment: An old way of saying what? Can you give us some context please?

Comment: Related questions: [Gender neutral reflexive pronoun — equivalent to “himself” and “herself”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35135/gender-neutral-reflexive-pronoun-equivalent-to-himself-and-herself) & [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Comment: What JLG said. Personally, I think *themself/themselves* is more common today than it ever was. It used to be a somewhat "dialectal/informal" usage, but its PC gender-neutral qualities are helping it to gain currency.

Comment: The pairs are *one* + *oneself*, not *one* + *themself*.  If **someone** asked you whether **they** could do it for **themself**, that is different from whether **one** should ask whether **one** can do it for **oneself**.  See?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Singular *they*](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/June05Eye.pdf) is a usage hallowed by time -- it's actually older than singular *you* -- and, since reflexive pronouns are inflected on **both** the pronoun root **and** the *-self/-selves* reflexive suffix (e.g, *my`[sg]`-self`[sg]`* vs *our`[pl]`-selves`[pl]`*), the correct reflexive for singular *they* is [*themself*](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/004285.html).

Dictionaries, by the way, are not reliable sources for grammar, just as grammars are not reliable sources for lexical meaning.

Comment: I treat the OED as, among other things, a corpus, if a rather specialised kind of corpus.

Comment: I found 41 occurrences in the OED, from Caxton's 1483 "Humble themself the one ageynst the other", to a 1978 quotation from _American Speech_ "Personal singular _you_ similarly takes what is formally a plural verb form (_are, were_), as do French _vous_, German _Sie_, and Russian _vy_; as with singular _they-themself_, this `pluralization' of singular _you_ can be said to follow reflexivization (whence a plural verb but a singular reflexive _yourself_)."

Answer (score 4):

The reflexive and emphatic pronoun is *themselves*. The OED has no entry for *themself*. An example of its use in the way you have in mind might be:

> If a student needs to ask for permission to leave the campus during
>   the week, they must do it themselves, and not ask a fellow student to
>   do it on their behalf.

Comment: That example sentence would become much less awkward if you simply replaced "a student" with "students". I know this site tends to be a strong proponent of singular *they*, but that doesn't mean it should be used at every opportunity.

Comment: Google Books claims 939K entries for [themself](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=themself&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 1590K for [theirself](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=theirself&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I don't have a problem with either, regardless of OED.

Comment: @Marthaª: I know, but I was trying to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I was reporting the OED, not necessarily commending it for its lack of an entry for 'themself'. FWIW, the COCA has 96 records for 'themself' (BNC 26), 23 for 'theirself' (BNC 16), 41 for 'theirselves' (40 ) and 91825 for 'themsleves' (BNC 23012).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED actually mentions *themself* under its *themselves* headword, saying “in Standard English *themself* was the normal form to c1540, but disappeared c1570”. It occurs in 52 citations. Burchfield mentions it. I think it is not very uncommon these days, where people use *themself* when the antecedent is “singular they”. I wouldn’t consider *themselves* wrong, but this may someday change: we don’t say *yourselves* for a single person any longer.

Comment: @tchrist: Thanks for your more thorough research. But 'not very uncommon'? The corpora suggest otherwise.