# Why is the plural pronoun **them** used here?

Tags: pronouns

Look at the following sentence that I just saw while viewing a profile:

```
Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.
```

As it looks, `them` refers to `this user`, right?
`This user` refers to one person; however, the pronoun `them` is used which refers to many people and seems incompatible.

Can somebody explain why this sentence is right and why `him`/`her` aren't used?

Comment: Please refer to a discussion of **singular they** at the grammar site of your choice. Singular "they" had a long history of usage, far before the concern over "gender-neutral language" brought it back into vogue.

Comment: And also of [What is a proper gender-neutral form of _himself_ or _herself_?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68767/15299).