# The hidden flaw in "singular they"—what to do about reflexive pronouns?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, personal-pronouns, reflexives, singular-they

We have [a highly regarded answer by nohat](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/2303) to a question about gender-neutral pronouns, in which he points to the "singular they" and its long history of use in English. (Note that he also advises against using it.) Example:

> If someone wants to watch TV tonight, they'll have to do the dishes.

This avoids having to say "he or she" in mixed-gender situations. Okay, fine. I'm not going to get my panties in a bunch if people want to talk this way.

But it occurrs to me that "singular they"—infelicitous at the best of times—really falls apart when extended into the realm of reflexive pronouns:

> If someone wants to watch TV tonight, they'll have to do the dishes **all by themselves**. [?]

That feels very wrong. The only alternative, if one paints oneself into that corner, is to flip it back to singular:

> If someone wants to watch TV tonight, they'll have to do the dishes **all by themself**. [???]

That feels worse.

If I'm to state this as a question, I guess I would put it thus: How can use of a "singular they" truly be reconciled? Is it really as much of a linguistic dead end as it feels to me?

Comment: I've used "themself" before in that situation; it does feel a bit strange. But I'm entirely comfortable using "themselves" for the singular.

Comment: The OED has citations for the word *"themself"* from 1382. It presumably dropped in frequency when grammarians started denigrating singular *"they"*, but now that singular *"they"* has been rehabilitated, there is no reason not to use *"themself"*. The similar word *"ourself"* is a perfectly good pronoun.

Comment: This is what happens when you force a pronoun that is normally plural into a singular role: awkward constructions ensue. The traditional neutral *he* is the best "solution", stylistically.

Comment: @Cerberus awkward is in the ear of the beholder.

Comment: @Cerberus: singular *they* and the corresponding reflexive pronoun *themself* have been used in English since the 14th century. Sometime one or two centuries ago, grammarians started discouraging its use, leaving a hole in the English language. (Although some people kept using it; I grew up using it, despite teachers saying that it was incorrect.) With the birth of feminism, people started looking for a singular gender-neutral pronoun to fill this hole. The current consensus is that the best candidate to fill this hole is *"they"*.

Comment: @PeterShor but are they singular uses? I don't have access to the OED right now, but the date suggests Wycliffe, and Wycliffe used *themself* as the plural third-person reflexive.

Comment: @Jon: you're right, it's Wycliffe ... for the singular use you have to go to the 15th century: *"Euery creature That ys gylty and knowyth thaym-self coulpable."* and *"Eche of theym sholde..make theymselfe redy."*

Comment: A separate problem with the singular *they* is that it can introduce ambiguity when there are also others referred to in the same sentence. Whereas *she*, *he*, *one*, or *it* is clearly distinguished from a plural *they* (or *theirs* or *them* etc.) in the same context, singular *they* is ambiguous (aka variable capture). Not a big deal, but it means splitting sentences or jumping through other (minor) hoops to be clear.

Comment: I don't have a problem with using ***themselves*** reflexively of a singular subject, and that's what I'd normally use. On the other hand, I don't have any problem with ***themself*** either, and I'm sure I'll have used it myself many a time. Even though Google Books claims only 90 other writers who were each brave enough to [do it themself](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22do+it+themself%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (plus 126 who [do it **theirself**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22do+it+theirself%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl))

Comment: @PeterShor: We all know that, but I'm not sure how it is relevant. The construction just leads to awkwardness, like the above. Consensus there is not. Besides, I believe it was not nearly as common in early modern times as it has now become.

Comment: Singular *you* takes *yourself* while plural *you* takes *yourselves*. Use the same model. And magisterial *we*? Hm, *ourself*? :-)

Comment: @tchrist: We are not amused!

Comment: 'themself' sounds really bad to me 'and 'themselves' sounds perfectly fine for singular reflexive. But if we have to, what @tchrist said works.

Comment: Themself looks like somebody missing a limb and sounds like a joke. The singular themselves looks and sounds OK. (with all due respect to the disabled).

Comment: @Cerberus "This is what happens when you force a pronoun that is normally plural into a singular role: awkward constructions ensue". Indeed, _exactly_ what happened when people forced the plural pronoun _you_ into a singular role. Next to the reflexive _yourselves_ you all of a sudden got the awkward _yourself_. I tend to only accept criticism on the use of singular _they_ from people that _also_ shun the use of singular _you_. Otherwise, hold thy horses.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't understand why you deleted your answer (which I agree with, so just for devilment I've voted to reopen it). As I understand things, Robusto doesn't like ***themself/theirself*** because they *only* exist in the context of "singular they". This factor does affect my usage in "casual/careless" contexts, where I'm capable of using ***themselves*** in the "dishes" example cited above, even though I would always use ***themself*** if I was paying attention. But the "rule" is, as you say, pretty straightforward (and "natural", apart from that factor).

Comment: Isn't this question POB? If Robusto finds the plural "themselves" jarring, and the singular "themself" awkward and, perhaps, ugly, does anyone have the right to say he is wrong? Is he wrong? Isn't a question of personal preference? I often write "she or he" and on the rare instances "herself or himself", I don't find them to be particularly cumbersome as long as the number of instances are kept down to a minimum.

Comment: @oerkelens: I'm sure that was terribly awkward at the time, and I would certainly not have accepted it. But at some point one has to move on. Now is not that time.

Comment: @Mitch: Kind Sir, please speak English! You know very well what should be done with the women...

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Anybody has the right to find any construction jarring, awkward, distasteful, and/or ugly. However, as you point out, this is a case of _de gustibus non disputandum est_; personally, [I find nothing wrong with either reflexive, when appropriately applied](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/68767/15299). They're doubly inflected, after all, and there oughta be a use for all that morphology.

Comment: @Andrew Leach   So the "canonical" answer is: There is no justification *not* to use *themself* because *some* authors used it 300 and 150 years ago, and there is no reason why the singular pronoun "they" shouldn't have a singular reflexive pronoun. So why not "themselves"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That's what it feels like. I'm almost sorry I raised this question now, because I really don't feel any closer to satisfaction at this point. The consensus seems to be that the construction is used by some, has been used by some, and will continue to be used by some, in both singular and plural forms, so I should just stop whining about it.

Comment: Why not write an answer?  Before anyone accuses me of sour grapes, I upvoted Sven's answer. He writes well, he put forward a good argument, and it was not only based on personal preference, there was some convincing evidence. But, it is not a "canonical" answer. Not as I understand it.

Comment: In a lot of cases I know enough about questions I'm asking to write a convincing answer. This isn't one of them, unfortunately.

Comment: Just for the record, I don't consider my answer canonical, nor did I submit it in the hope that others would imagine it to be canonical. I simply wanted to make an argument in favor of _themself_ as a rational option for singular reflexive pronoun.

Comment: @SvenYargs: I upvoted your answer because I respect you argument, even though I don't find it—or anything else here—satisfying or "canonical." I don't even remember now what I was thinking in asking this. Hey, it was Christmas Eve. Maybe I had started drinking early in the day that day.

Comment: It's rather funny how OP literally writes _The only alternative, if one paints **oneself** into that corner, is to flip it back to singular_ without noticing they're using an alternative themself right there: _If someone wants to watch TV tonight, one will have to do the dishes all by oneself._ Doesn't work with _somebody_, though.

Comment: @Crissov: You're assuming facts not in evidence. I'm a careful writer, and I do notice things like that. In fact, the choice to use *one* and *oneself* was deliberate. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### “Themself”

[image]

*Themself* was used in the past, and there is no law or authority that prohibits anyone from using it today. I have used it in personal correspondence, conscious of its rebellious and contradictory nature; however, I have to confess many of my correspondents are in the field of language teaching, and they tend to be more open-minded.

Although the singular *themself* is gaining currency, it would be an arduous challenge for anyone to produce a recent  government bill, act, tax form, or any official English document that contains the actual reflexive pronoun. And if they could produce a formal document, it would be akin to seeing an exotic and engendered butterfly in the wild.

It's simply not done; not today, not in a formal context simply because it looks “wrong”. *Themself* looks dialectal, a word that an uneducated native speaker person might use. While the singular *they*, *their* and *them* are extremely common in speech—and increasingly so in writing as it avoids having to write the cumbersome *he or she*; *his or her*; *him or her*—yet many English native speakers consider *themself* not a “proper word”, and whenever instances of *ourself* and *themself* appear in writing, these words stick out like a sore thumb.

---

### Those in favour of “themself”

Pam Peters in ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ advocates:

> The singular reference in ‘themself’ obviously serves a purpose, especially after an indefinite noun or pronoun. If we allow the use of ‘they’/’them’/’their’ for referring to the singular, ‘themself’ seems more consistent than ‘themselves‘. We make use of ”yourself‘ alongside ‘yourselves’ in just the same way. ‘Themself’ has the additional advantage of being gender-free, and thus preferable to both ‘himself’ and ‘himself/herself‘. It’s time to reinstate it to the set of reflexive pronouns!

### Those against …

From an article in [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004285.html), March 08, 2007, two American English authorities condemn the use of *themself*

> 1. As MWDEU (Merriam-Webster Dictionary of English Usage) 1989 puts it (p. 898):
>
> This use of themself is similar to the use of *they*, *their*, and *them* in reference to singular terms...  Such use of *they*, *their*, and *them* is old and well established, but this use is not.
>
> 2. Wilson's Columbia Guide (1993) is stern on the matter (p. 435):
>
> *Theirselves* and *themself* for *themselves* are limited to Vulgar English or imitations of it; both are shibboleths.

adding that

> *Themself* can also occur as an unfortunate result of trying to avoid using a gender-explicit reflexive pronoun by using a blend of the plural *them* with the singular *self*.  The choices are *themselves* or *himself or herself* or both the last two...

### Themselves

An Ngram showing *themself* tells us that it existed and exists. An [Ngram that compares *themself* and *themselves*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=themself%2C%20themselves&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthemself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthemselves%3B%2Cc0) reflects its usage more accurately.

[image]

### Him(self) or herself

An Ngram that compares *themself* (blue line); *himself or herself* (red line);  *him or herself* (green) and *herself and himself* (yellow) **tells us that the majority of writers (and editors) feel more comfortable using a longer equivalent than the succinct *themself*.**

[image]

On Google Books, the politically-correct expression, "herself or himself", produces around [1,480 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=20&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=bks&q=%22herself%20or%20himself%22&oq=%22herself%20or%20himself%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.3741.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.I8lJNJzEiVg). Here are some examples:

> The differentiation between self and not-self certainly seems related to the growth of the object concept, during which the child learns to see **herself or himself** as an object in space and time, separate from the mother.
>   <sub>*Research Manual in Child Development* 2003</sub>

1963, *[Standard Civil Code of the State of California](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GClIAQAAIAAJ&q=%22herself%20or%20himself%22&dq=%22herself%20or%20himself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAjgUahUKEwixpv-k8afHAhXHvxQKHVMZAh0)*

> the case may be, for the permanent support and maintenance of [*3*] **herself or himself**, and may include therein at her or his discretion an action for support, maintenance and education of the children of said marriage during their minority.

and as recently as 2009, *[Code of Federal Regulations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TL26nTDlh-gC&pg=PA73&dq=%22herself%20or%20himself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBmoVChMI-PKF5vGnxwIVRzIaCh2QPQH8#v=onepage&q=%22herself%20or%20himself%22&f=false)*

> (a) An ALJ [Administrative Law Judge] may disqualify **herself or himself** at any time. (b) Until the filing of the ALJ's decision. either party may move that the ALJ disqualify **herself or himself** for personal bias or other valid cause. The party shall file with the ALJ, promptly ..

---

Whereas *himself or herself* gets  [8,190 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=20&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=bks&q=%22himself%20or%20herself%22&oq=%22himself%20or%20herself%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.452725.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.TSKXY6ysnOE)

*[George Herbert Mead and Human Conduct](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=u3BOxaRysbYC&pg=PA57&dq=%22himself%20or%20herself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMInZb6sP6nxwIVgVwaCh3GHwpb#v=onepage&q=%22himself%20or%20herself%22&f=false)*, 2004

> He sees it, in the first instance, as being merely the object that **the individual is to himself or herself**. Obviously, human beings can, and do, think of themselves as being a given kind of object. The human being may see himself or herself as male or female, young or old, rich or poor, married or unmarried …

Interestingly, the authors use the impersonal pronouns *it* and ***itself*** when referring to babies and small infants on page 58.

> The human infant or very young child is not an object to **itself**. While in the eyes of others it acts as a baby, **it doesn't recognize itself** as a baby. It doesn't see itself as someone who is helpless, gets sick, cries a lot, spends a lot of time sleeping, ...

In a formal or technical register, *himself or herself*, will usually be preferred. And it seems highly unlikely that it will change in the near future.

*Criminal Law*, 2010, page 357

> Section 2 Any person who
>   (a) Purposely engages in a course of conduct directed at a specific person that would cause a reasonable person to fear bodily injury to **himself or herself** or a member of his or her immediate family or to fear the death of himself or herself or a member of his or her immediate family; and
>   (b) Has knowledge or should have knowledge that the specific person will be placed in reasonable fear of bodily injury to **himself or herself** or a member of his or her immediate family or induce fear in the specific individual of the death of himself or herself or a member of his or her immediate family; is guilty of stalking.

---

### And those sitting on the fence

In 2013, Catherine Soanes, guest blogger on [OxfordWords blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/01/themself/), and one of the editors of the OED 2nd edition 2005, argued:

> Given that it’s now largely acceptable to use *they*, *them*, or *their* instead of the more long-winded ‘he or she’, ‘him or her’, or ‘his or her’ (especially in conjunction with indefinite pronouns such as *anyone* or *somebody*) it might be argued that, logically, it should also be OK to use *themself*, it being viewed as the corresponding singular form of *themselves*. **However, this isn’t yet the case, so beware of *themself* for now!** The correct versions of the opening examples in this section should be:
>
> 1. It’s not an expensive way for somebody to make *themselves* feel good.
> 2. Anyone would find *themselves* thinking similar thoughts.
>
> Of course, if you dislike the use of gender-neutral third-person plural pronouns for singular subjects, or you’re working to a style guide that prohibits them, you should reword the sentences so as to incorporate gender-specific third-person singular pronouns instead:
>
> 1. It’s not an expensive way for somebody to make *himself or herself* feel good.
> 2. Anyone would find *himself or herself* thinking similar thoughts.
>
> […] To sum up, the wheel has not yet come full circle and **‘themself’ remains a standard English outcast. . . for now.**

### If you dislike using “themself”, what can you do?

The OP's example:

> If someone wants to watch TV tonight, **they**'ll have to do the dishes
>   all by **themselves**

Sound perfectly acceptable to my ears. In speech and in an informal context, it is perfectly fine. For anyone who dislikes this solution I would suggest the following:

If I am speaking to more than one person

> i) For **those** who want to watch TV tonight, **they**'ll have to do the dishes all by **themselves**

or to any individual, male or female

> ii) If **someone** wants to watch TV tonight, **he or she** will have to do the dishes
>   all by **themselves**

or you could try this "clunkier" version

> iii) If **someone** wants to watch TV tonight, **he or she** will have to do the dishes all by **him or herself**

If I *had* to use this particular construction, for efficiency's sake, I'd choose *him or herself*, which is well-documented and represented by the green line in the third Ngram chart.

Comment: Truth to say, this is a more comprehensive and balanced analysis than mine, and I think it deserves serious consideration as a "canonical" response.

Comment: @SvenYargs: I've risen from the grave to award the checkmark to this response, notwithstanding your own fine (and already much awarded) effort. This answer strikes the real-world balance I think I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, he or she, themselves sound natural, if you're not looking to formalize. I prefer to shoot myself in the feet [caveat: joke] than to use "themself".

Answer (score 24):

John Fortescue, [*The Difference Between an Absolute and Limited Monarchy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fS4JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA13&dq=%22themself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI2bPw_9ymxwIVByqICh0DeQAJ#v=onepage&q=%22themself%22&f=false) (written around 1471 [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Fortescue_%28judge%29) but published under that name in 1714) uses the word *themself* three times in the course of his discourse:

> But afterward, whan Mankynd was more mansuete, and better disposyd to Vertue, Grete Communalties, as was the Feliship, that came into this Lond with *Brute*, wyllyng to be unyed and made a Body Politike callid a Realme, hvyng an Heed to governe it; as after the Saying of the Philosopher, ever Communaltie unyed of many parts must needs have an Heed; than they chose the same *Brute* to be their Heed and Kyng. And they and he upon this Incorporation and Institution, and onyng [uniting] of **themself** into a Realme, ordeynyd the same Realme so to be rulyd and justyfyd by such Lawys, as they al would assent unto ; which Law therfor is callid *Politicum*; and bycause it is mynystrid by a Kyng, it is callid Regale.
>
> ...
>
> Wherefor the holy Spirites and Angels, that may not syne, wex old, but syke, or hurt **themself**, have more power than we that may harme our self, with al the Defawts.
>
> ...
>
> For so the Kyng schal lese the Officers for an singular Service he schal have of them, or that the same Officers schal thynk **themself** beholdyng to the Kyng for their Offices, which his Highness hath gevyn them at the Contemplation and Requeste of their Masters; and for no Reward of any Service that they have done or schal do unto hymself.

An [editor's footnote](https://books.google.com/books?id=fS4JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA13&dq=%22themselves;+from+the+Saxon+Pronoun%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIgd3VhaWnxwIVRQmSCh1dtAce#v=onepage&q=%22themselves%3B%20from%20the%20Saxon%20Pronoun%22&f=false) in the 1719 edition of this treatise explains Fortescue's use of *themself*:

> i.e. *themſelves*; from the Saxon Pronoun hem-ꞅẏlꝼ, from thence comes *themſelf*; the plural Number in Saxon being *ſylf*, as well as the ſingular. *Hickeſ. Gram.* 32.

So we have a word *themself* of long standing; and we also have, in recent decades, widespread use of *they* to serve as a gender-neutral singular pronoun substituting for "a person." Under the circumstances—and given that the referent for the reflexive pronoun is clearly singular—I'm not at all sure why anyone would be inclined to prefer sentence 1 to sentence 2 below:

> 1. Each person must figure it out for themselves.
> 2. Each person must figure it out for themself.

Or even more starkly, why anyone would prefer sentence 3 to sentence 4 below:

> 3. If someone paints themselves into a corner, they won't know what to do.
> 4. If someone paints themself into a corner, they won't know what to do.

It's as though, having grudgingly relinquished *he*, *him*, and *his* in favor of *they*, *them*, and *their* as the default pronouns associated with "a [generic] person," the person making the concession has insisted "but you have to replace *himself* with *themselves*, too, for consistency." I see no reason to accept that proviso.

---

A related issue arises in the context of the royal reflexive pronoun. A letter from King James I to the Earl of Bristol, dated October 8, 1623, in [*Journals of the House of Lords*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bCVDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=%22ourself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIrPPW7O-mxwIVlEiICh0MKQ_M#v=onepage&q=%22ourself%22&f=false), volume 3 adopts *ourself* (or rather, *Ourself*) as the reflexive pronoun:

> We have received your's [that is, your letter], brought us by Greysly; and the Copy of your's to Our dear Son; and We cannot forbear to let you know, how well We esteem your dutiful, discreet, and judicious Relation and humble Advice to **Ourself** and Our son; whereupon, having ripely deliberated with **Ourself**, and communicated with Our dear Son, We have resolved, with the great Liking of Our Son, to rest upon that Security, and in Point of Doubt of the Infanta's taking a religious Order, which you, in your Judgement shall think meet.

To similar effect, William Tidd, [*Practical Forms, and Entries of Proceedings: In the Courts of Queen's Bench, Common Pleas, and Exchequer of Pleas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jhtHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA599&dq=%22ourself%22+Victoria&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI4K7j1OymxwIVx5uICh0RPgH9#v=onepage&q=%22ourself%22%20Victoria&f=false), eighth edition (1840) has this form for a writ of replevin (among many other writs similarly formulated):

> Victoria, &c. (351.) To the sheriff of ————, greeting: We command you, that justly and without delay you cause to be replevied to *A. B.* his cattle goods and chattels, which *C. D.* took and unjustly detains, as it is said; and afterwards cause him to be justly remedied in this behalf, that we may no longer hear any clamour thereupon, for want of justice. Witness **ourself** at *Westminster*, the ———— day of ————, in the ———— year of our reign.

And just as King James and Queen Victoria very reasonably distinguish between the group *we* that yields *ourselves* and the royal *we* that yields *ourself* when used reflexively, it seems to me that writers and speakers ought to be able to distinguish between a group *they* that yields *themselves* and a singular *they* that yields *themself* when used reflexively. In acknowledgment of the "royal we," we could call it the "commoner they."

Comment: Out of curiosity, how often do you use the term *themself* yourself? Judging from your answer, it seems you are a strong supporter, and yet, I haven't found a single instance in any of your answers posted. Whereas I have seen  John Lawler using *themself* on more than one occasion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I wouldn't use _themself_ or _themselves_ as a reflexive singular pronoun in writing unless absolutely forced to it—and I can't recall that that has ever happened. Speech, though, is a whole nother ballgame. Here in California I have occasionally heard _themself_ used in the way I discuss in my answer—and in some specific instances (such as the two that I cite as examples above) it sounds more natural and less self-consciously stilted to me than _themselves_ used singularly. ...

Comment: ... English embraced the nonsexist singular _they_ as a standard form relatively recently, and I don't consider the reflexive form settled yet as a point of standard usage. As I say in my answer, I would prefer to see _themself_ win out as the singular reflexive form—but in my writing I intend to avoid both alternatives. That's because I firmly believe that writing effectively is to some extent a matter of avoiding distracting formulations (like "whole nother") so that as much of the reader's attention as possible is directed to the writer's argument rather than to his or her word choice.

Comment: Note that in speech _himself_ and _themself_ would both be elided to /ṃ'sɛlf/ and one can hear what one expects to hear, regardless of what the speaker believes'ṃself to have said.

Comment: Plus, 'singular _they_' and _themself_ have been around for half a millenium at least. I found 41 occurrences of _themself_ in the OED, from Caxton's 1483 "Humble themself the one ageynst the other", to a 1978 quotation from _American Speech_: "Personal singular _you_ similarly takes what is formally a plural verb form (_are, were_), as do French _vous_, German _Sie_, and Russian _vy_; as with singular _they-themself_, this `pluralization' of singular _you_ can be said to follow reflexivization (whence a plural verb but a singular reflexive _yourself_)."

Comment: @SvenYargs I've added the special characters you were wanting to the editor's footnote.

Comment: @MετάEd: Thanks for adding the special characters. One fix shows up oddly on my screen, however—as "hem-ꞅẏlꝼ," with two domino-like rectangles bookending the ẏl. Does that word look correct on your screen?

Comment: It does look correct, both in the post and in your comment. I'd say your device does not have a font with those characters in it.

Answer (score 7):

Although the form *themself* sounds utterly barbarous to many anglophone ears including mine, OED indeed lists it, with examples of the relevant usage ranging from the fifteenth century (four examples) to 2007:

> 2. In anaphoric reference to a singular pronoun or noun of undetermined gender or where the meaning implies more than one: himself or herself. Cf. *they* pron. 2, *them* pron. 4.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=themself&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) also shows that the form is not exclusively a recent one. Those who think of singular *they* as a barbarism attributable to second-wave feminism might find some seeming confirmation in the fairly steady rise in frequency since circa 1960, but the frequency peak of 1819 remains unmatched since.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your questions:

> How can use of a "singular they" truly be reconciled? Is it really as much of a linguistic dead end as it feels to me?

The questions themselves clearly assume the absurdity of "themself" and rightly so, despite the **past** trace of its usage, which, in and of itself, does not really mean anything about its **current** usage, for its historical usage is a non-issue here. The only issue is its current usage.

This irreconcilability that's mentioned in the OP, it seems to me, emanates from the apparently illogical naming of the usage "they" as "singular they". Before attacking the fallacy of this naming, let me use the OP's example sentence and tweak it a little:

> *If someone wants to watch TV tonight, they **have** to do the dishes.*

Here, *they* is used to refer to *someone*, instead of the more cumbersome "he or she", and thus it's called "singular they". But if they were really singular, how come you use the plural verb ***have*** instead of the singular ***has***? So if we are to determine whether *they* here is singular or plural, I'd say it's as plural as can be.

It's just that this "plural they" can be used to refer to a singular antecedent *someone*. Does that automatically make it singular? THAT I don't know. Please someone let me know if there's such a rule in English.

Unless and until someone finds me such a rule, I think it'd be better to call it "neutral they" if you had to have a name for it. And yes, "they" is already neutral before we call it "neutral they", so what I'm saying is that we're just using the same "they" in order to avoid all the controversy over political correctness and at the same time to stay away from the cumbersome "he or she".

I bet this answers the OP's question regarding whether to use "themselves" as in:

> *If someone wants to watch TV tonight, they **have** to do the dishes all by **themselves**.*

### ANSWER

And the answer, if you have yet to get it, is that, insofar as you readily accept the plural verb ***have***, you should be able to have little difficulty accepting the plural reflexive pronoun ***themselves***.

### PS

As for the argument that some people accept the form "themself" and that we should be able to use "themself" as a singular counterpart of "themselves" as we use "yourself" as a singular counterpart of "yourselves", if your dialect already accepts "themself" as a correct form, I guess you can use it as you have been all along.

But if your dialect doesn't accept it as of yet, "themself" will sound awkward to you no matter how persuasive you find the argument for using it, because you can't just change language usage overnight just because it's more logical. It takes time for the usage to spread and be accepted by the majority of your dialect. Until that day comes, you'll have to stick to "themselves".

Comment: How does a particular usage spread and become accepted **without** being used? Chicken and egg, perhaps; but if you stick to *themselves* then the day will never come!

Comment: @Andrew Leach: You may be right about that, but that doesn't automatically allow you to go around and misuse 'themself' whenever and wherever you will. The OP's question was not about the original poster being willing to be a pioneer or something but about whether it's appropriate to use 'themself' in a dialect where it's not yet accepted as natural.

Comment: @AndrewLeach How many times have you yourself written the term, *yourself*, in any of the 1,062 answers you posted? I think there is a lot of hypocrisy on this website, and I'd suggest that users who positively advocate the use of "themself" begin using it themselves, otherwise the day when "themself" will be fully acceptable will never come.

Comment: The pronoun *you* also takes "plural" verb agreement when it is used to refer to a single person, but we still use *yourself* in this context ("you **have** to do the dishes all by **yourself**").

Answer (score 1):

It is, presently, a grammatical dead end when followed narrowly, but there are sometimes ways out if you look far enough out to the sides.

Using "one" or "that person" as a reference to what the pronoun is replacing can be effective and grammatical.

In your question, the bolded phrase ("all by themself/themselves") could be more concisely replaced by an adjective like "alone" that does not require a pronoun.

> *If someone wants to watch TV tonight, that person will have to do the dishes alone.*

When written (e.g. in dialogue), this may strike a stronger and/or more formal tone than intended in an informal setting, but it does seem to resolve the grammatical challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The popular practice now is to allow people to choose their pronouns.

There are a vast array of options available: http://askanonbinary.tumblr.com/pronouns

The problem here is that in English, pronouns are largely considered a [closed class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_class).

> In linguistics, a closed class (or closed word class) is a word class to which **new items are rarely and with difficulty added**, and that usually contains a relatively small number of items
> ...
> Different languages have different word classes as open class and closed class – for example, **in English, pronouns are closed class** and verbs are open class...

We have a largely static vernacular attempting to reflect a fairly revolutionized way of thinking.

To answer your question - yes, it is just as much a dead end as you feel it to be. If you personally are having trouble with someone that you want to refer to with pronouns, I recommend discovering by which pronouns that person wishes to be referred to. May auto-correct have mercy on you.

---

In the case of a generic reference to someone of undetermined gender, rather than someone explicitly identifying as non-gender-binary, I am aware of two options outside of 'singular they.'

'One; oneself' refers adequately to a non-specific sentient being. 'This/that person' is also an acceptable reference, but leads back to a singular 'they' case when substituted once more.

If pronouns are a problem, sticking to the noun you would be replacing is also always an option.

Comment: By the way, I don't mean to endorse the entirety of the pronouns offered in that Tumblr link.

Language is a medium for communication. When the medium doesn't suit its purpose, you expand it. Until the standards-making entities catch up to our need to express these ideas, I believe it is much more appropriate to tolerate free expression than to enforce an outdated standard.

Comment: I'm not advocating against free expression, and I understand you are not trying to certify that Tumblr link's entire catalogue, but if your point is that language is "a medium for communication" I wonder how a bunch of made-up pronouns could possibly communicate except to other aficionados of those abstruse coinages?

Comment: @Robusto The idea is that in such cases you agree on pronouns when you begin conversation with someone in that group.

Language is a social arrangement. If, for example, you were to engage in philosophical debates, you'd have to agree on a number of definitions in order to ensure you're communicating on common ground; English words that don't quite fit are leveraged into new meanings.

These pronouns are much the same. You agree that existing words are insufficient, and you agree which words you will use as placeholders.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the question - all you discuss are alternatives to the singular/generic they, not its reflexive.

Answer (score 0):

What's the deal with reflexive pronouns? They have to match the noun that is doing the action to itself. "He is washing herself" doesn't work because "herself" can only be used when the relevant preceding noun denotes a female. That's an easy case. "Themselves" is interesting because, before it was used as a gender-neutral singular reflexive pronoun, it was the reflexive pronoun for plural nouns (or noun phrases like "Bob and Bob").

It has been awhile since I've read the relevant work in semantics, but pronouns and other deictic words have both a fixed linguistic meaning and a contextually-dependent part (which is actually determined by the fixed linguistic meaning). For example, when I wrote "since I've read ..." the word "I" means (and always means) [insert the producer of the utterance], an insertion will change from context to context. When "they" started moonlighting as a singular pronoun, it got a *second* fixed linguistic meaning. The issue with "themselves" is, I suspect, merely one of being uttered less frequently than "they" as a singular pronoun. Because of that, it's lagging behind. Soon enough, though, it will acquire the meaning that corresponds to "they"'s new meaning. I must admit that, for me, it already has.

Comment: So are you saying that *themselves* is the right pronoun for singular *they,* or *themself*? **That's** the question, and this answer only implies an answer (which I **think** is that you favour *themselves* over what [from Sven's research] is hardly a neologism in *themself*).

Comment: The queen uses *ourself* for the singular *we*; everybody uses *yourself* for the singular *you*; why not *themself* for the singular *they*?

Answer (score -4):

I do agree that it's a dead end.  Alternatives for your particular example:

1. He who wishes to watch TV tonight, must do the dishes all by
   himself.
2. *(Variant of #1)* Anyone wishing to watch TV tonight must do the dishes all by himself.
3. If anyone wants to watch TV tonight, you'll have to do the dishes
   all by yourself / yourselves (depending on how many people are being
   addressed).

Note, #1 and #2 work just fine in languages where *everything* has a gender, such as Spanish.  So I don't see why we can't do it in English.

Comment: Why are women exempt? In sentence 1. it definitely sounds like a) there are only men present, or, b) a woman is talking to a group of men, or c) for whatever reason, the women in the house are exempt from this chore.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - No, not exempt.  Inspired by what works in some other languages (for example, Spanish, *el que quiera mirar la tele deberá lavar los trastes por su cuenta*), where *he* can be used in an ungendered way, I see no reason not to do this in English more often.  The Danes got rid of the formal version of "you" in *one generation!*  I believe that "he" and "man" should be for everyone.  "She's the man for the job." "She's my right-hand man."

Comment: Many would disagree with you, the time when the pronoun *he* represented both sexes is on its way out. I believe my observations on your first sentence clearly illustrates the drawbacks and limitations of using: *he*, *his*, *him* and *himself* as gender neutral.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Hopefully in the context it would be clear.  Eye contact with those who tend to shirk dish duty would probably help the arrow meet its mark.  ---  Oh, I thought of a word that's become less gender-specific over time -- "guys."