# For someone having taught themself

Tags: grammar

Please look at the following sentence and tell me which sentence is correct?

1) "I play viola well for someone ***having taught themselves***"

and

2) "I play viola well for someone ***having taught themself***"

And

3) "I play viola well for someone ***having taught myself***"

Thank you.

Comment: Not 1,because presumably you're only one person. #2 and #3 are okay, with #2 being better or more logical. But I'd use *himself* or *herself*, matching the gender to *I*.

Comment: First is wrong because of number disagreement. Second is correct. Use "himself" instead of "myself" third sentence.

Comment: For an excellent discussion of themselves and themself, see  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617/the-hidden-flaw-in-singular-they-what-to-do-about-reflexive-pronouns.  What I take from that discussion is that you can use either 1) or 2).   As for 3), either "for having taught myself"  or "for someone having taught himself/herself."

Answer (score 2):

"I play viola well for someone *self-taught*."

or

"I play viola well for someone who is *self-taught*."

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is "I play viola well for someone having taught himself" (or "herself" if the speaker is female). You can also use "themselves" to be gender-neutral. "Myself" is incorrect because the pronoun refers to "someone", so it should be in the third person. "Themself" is not universally recognized as a valid word, so it should probably be avoided, at least in formal settings.

Here's a citing from *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged* showing the "himself/herself" sense of "themselves":

> 3:  himself, herself — used with a singular antecedent that is
>   indefinite or that does not specify gender