# Self or Ourselves or Oneself

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which one is correct to say OR what's the right way to say -

> Each one of us thinks about oneself all the time.

or

> Each one of us thinks about himself/herself all the time.

or

> Each one of us thinks about ourselves all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The proper word for this is *ourself*, which is the singular reflexive pronoun corresponding to *we*, because *each of us* is a singular construction, even though *us* is first person plural.

This word is in the [Lexico dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541569/self-or-ourselves-or-oneself) (although it is not used very often):

> **ourself:** *first person plural*

1. Used instead of “ourselves,” typically when “we” refers to people in general rather than a definite group of people.
   *[reflexive]* ‘we must choose which aspects of ourself to express to the world’

You could use *ourselves* in *Lexico's* example, but only *ourself* works well in the OP's sentence.

Comment: Personally, I still prefer "singular they" ***themself*** here, but it's interesting that exactly the same plurality clash arises with ***themselves / ourselves***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Traditionally, the right pronoun for *one of us* would have been *his*, but that has now been deprecated, and is being replaced by *our* or *their*. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=one+of+us+has+his%2Cone+of+us+has+our%2C+one+of+us+has+their&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20us%20has%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20us%20has%20our%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20us%20has%20their%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Yes - 40 years ago I'd unhesitatingly have opted for ***his*** here (without even considering the possibility that the text might *only* be intended to reference ***male*** behaviour). Times change.

Answer (score 0):

Short of including the somewhat clunky ***himself / herself*** form, the only really "correct" version here is the "gender-neutral"...

> *Each one of us [thinks about **themself**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thinks%20about%20themself%22)<sup>1</sup> all the time.*

Even native speakers get slightly confused in contexts like OP's example here (see [*The hidden flaw in “singular they”—what to do about reflexive pronouns?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617/the-hidden-flaw-in-singular-they-what-to-do-about-reflexive-pronouns), as asked previously on ELU). So you will often encounter the plural reflexive pronoun coupled with the singular verb form [*thinks about **themselves***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thinks%20about%20themselves%22)<sup>1</sup> in such contexts. But imho that's not "correct".

---

<sup>1</sup> Those are both links to *many* written instances in Google Books, but I must acknowledge that according to [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=thinks%20about%20themself%2Cthinks%20about%20themselves&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthinks%20about%20themselves%3B%2Cc0) plural ***themselves*** is actually far more common overall.

Answer (score -1):

Each one of us thinks about oneself all the time. - correct but old-fashioned

Each one of us thinks about himself/herself all the time. - correct but clunky

Each one of us thinks about ourselves all the time. - incorrect, mixed singular / plural

Each one of us thinks about self all the time. - correct but technical

or rephrase:

We all think about ourselves all of the time. - how I would write it.

Comment: It's not "old-fashioned" to reference "each one of us" using the pronoun ***one***. It's simply ***incorrect***, and always was.